# Recommended way to generate a java file from another java file

Tags: java, code-generation

Let us consider that I have a file which looks like following:

```
    @CreateFieldClass
    public class Queue {
      private String queueId;
      private int order;
      private boolean isActive;

      /* Getters and Setters */

    }
```

What I want is, If there is @CreateFieldClass annotation, I want to generat a new java file, in the same package which would look something like this

```
    public class QueueFields {
        public static final Field<Queue, String> QUEUE_ID = new Field<>(Queue.class, "queueId", DataType.STRING);
        public static final Field<Queue, Integer> ORDER = new Field<>(Queue.class,"order", DataType.NUMBER);
        public static final Field<Queue, Boolean> IS_ACTIVE = new Field<>(Queue.class,"isActive", DataType.Boolean);
    }
```

I have a mapping of Java type to the "DataType" mentioned above.
I know ASM is one option to consider, but are there any better recommendations or even some ASM tutorials/examples someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

To examine the annotated class, you can use reflection. Be aware that any fields that use generics will lose the generic parameter types due to erasure (if you need to get around that, then you need to parse the source code and work off of the parse tree). To generate the resulting class, you can do basic String concatenation. If you want a more structured method for generating code, I like the [codemodel](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-codemodel/) library.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the suggestion, but my use case is that:
* The end-user(A java programmer consuming my package) will generate the POJO mentioned
* When interacting with another manager class, the end-user, should be able to access the fields generated.

The use-case is very much how Lombok is used, where just by defining an annotation, constructors are generated and user can them in same code.

If I am going wrong with my understanding, please feel free to ask more question.

Thanks